# While call function I got this error HttpUserAgent.Errors.SendRequestFailure

Tags: javascript, .net

I got `HttpUserAgent.Errors.SendRequestFailure` error while I try to call  function. It works fine when I use **http** but when I try to call **https** URL side I get `HttpUserAgent.Errors.SendRequestFailure` error.

```
 function process() { 
    var ua = new HttpUserAgent();
    Script.log("test");
    var resp = ua.request("http://www.google.com");
   //var resp = ua.request("https://www.irctc.co.in"); 


    Script.log("test1");

  return resp;
 }
```

I get the following error:
  [image]

Comment: No, I don't see any error.  An error comes with lots of information.  Exception type.  Exception message.  Call stack.  And the same for all inner exceptions.  All I see here is an exception type.  That's worthless.  But if you can capture the exception details, do so and paste it into an [edit].  Images of exceptions will be punished swiftly.

Comment: What does this have to do with .NET? And do you really not get any more detail than that?

Comment: i know img is some poor quality. can you see it

Comment: Are you just trying to get content of some URL as a HTTP GET in JavaScript?